# Grid uniform row sizing

Tags: wpf, binding, grid

Currently I am using below code, I want to now bind the rows to a generic list. Also I want that rows height should be uniformly adjusted according to the height of Grid control.

```
<Grid  Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" Margin="2,6" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,6" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Hyperlink >
                          <TextBlock Text="Configure" />
                        </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,6" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Hyperlink >
                              <TextBlock Text="Import" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,6" Grid.Row="2">
                            <Hyperlink >
                              <TextBlock Text="Track" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,6" Grid.Row="3">
                            <Hyperlink >
                              <TextBlock Text="Exit" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Ankur - you should edit your question, rather than posting extra information as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

just have a look at the this which is using UniformGrid. Here you have to specify the number of Rows.

```
<UniformGrid Rows="4" >
    <TextBlock Margin="2,6" Grid.Row="0">                         <Hyperlink >                           <TextBlock Text="Configure" />                         </Hyperlink>                         </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Margin="2,6" Grid.Row="1">                             <Hyperlink >                               <TextBlock Text="Import" />                             </Hyperlink>                         </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Margin="2,6" Grid.Row="2">                             <Hyperlink >                               <TextBlock Text="Track" />                             </Hyperlink>                         </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Margin="2,6" Grid.Row="3">                             <Hyperlink >                               <TextBlock Text="Exit" />                             </Hyperlink>                         </TextBlock>

</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I dont want to hard code the number of rows they should be dynamically bind to generic list.